# Behavior of "and" with sets in Python

Tags: python, set

I know that if I want to get the intersection of two sets (or frozensets) I should use the ampersand `&`. Out of curiosity I tried to use the word 'and'

```
a = set([1,2,3])
b = set([3,4,5])
print(a and b) #prints set([3,4,5])
```

I am just curious why? what does this `and` represent when used with lists?

Comment: [What is Truth in Python?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: @thewolf: Good addition; let me add that link to the answer as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`x and y` just treats the whole `x` and `y` expressions as boolean values. If `x` is false, it returns `x`. Otherwise, it returns `y`. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) for details.

Both `set`s (as in your example) and `list`s (as in your question) are false if and only if they're empty. Again, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for details.

So, `x and y` will return `x` if it's empty, and `y` otherwise.

Comment: Nice and succinctly stated

Comment: @JonClements: Actually, looking at the docs, they're even nicer and more succinct. `x and y` is defined as "if `x` is false, then `x`, else `y`". That's really all that needs to be said.

Comment: Thank you. Just waiting the 10 minutes to accept the answer :)